# Do hardware & iOS app developed to connect with MFi certified Lightning serial cable needs to be enrolled in Apple MFi Program

Tags: ios, ipad, serial-communication, external-accessory, mfi

I want to get data from serial port of hardware into iPad by connecting it through a Lightning Serial Cable. The lightning serial cable is available with companies like RedPark which say they are MFi Certified.

I wanted to know if developing a hardware and iPad app that connects to lightning serial cable which itself is MFi Certified needs to be registered under MFi Licensing program?

Answer (score 0):

If the device is MFi, then you must go through the device manufacturer who owns the device protocol names you used. They must register your app before you submit it to the App Store. If you don't go through them first, your app will be rejected.